# Simple Multithreading in Python using Process

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a fairly simple program that I am writing in python that does not work for some reason. It will output the print statement above the 'join' line but not anything after it, including in change. Why?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

x = 0

def main():
    global x
    p = Process(target=change)
    p.start()
    print(x)
    p.join()
   # time.sleep(5)


def change():
    global x
    x = x +1
    print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Those aren't threads, they are processes.  Each process has its own separate memory, with its own private copy of x.

Comment: Shouldnt they share a global X? Either way, change does not run.

Comment: This prints just fine when i run your code.

Comment: @Reid: No, they don't share a global x.  That's threads.  Processes only share things which they are specifically [asked to share](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing this is what you want:

```
from threading import Lock, Thread

x = 0
lock = Lock()

def main():
    global x
    print(x)
    p = Thread(target=change, args=(1,))
    p2 = Thread(target=change, args=(2,))
    p.start()
    p2.start()
    p.join()
    p2.join()


def change(number):
    global x
    with lock:
        x = x + 1
        print('{} - coming from process #{}'.format(x, number))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
0
1 - coming from process #1
2 - coming from process #2
```

this you will notice will not work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Lock

x = 0
lock = Lock()

def main():
    global x
    print(x)
    p = Process(target=change, args=(1,))
    p2 = Process(target=change, args=(2,))
    p.start()
    p2.start()
    p.join()
    p2.join()


def change(number):
    global x
    with lock:
        x = x + 1
        print('{} - coming from process #{}'.format(x, number))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
0
1 - coming from process #1
1 - coming from process #2
```

thats because `Process` is like your exwife - she doesnt care about you, and will keep 100% of the stuff when she last saw it. So its 0 first, and it will copy `0` and will never look at `x` again. Unlike `Thread` she likes to share.